# Display a google.maps.Polyline with an address

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I try to display a google.maps.Polyline with addresses instead of lat/lng.

my code now is:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
```

Is there a chance to change the fixed LatLng floats into a text address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Maps' Reverse Geocoding service: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding